# Error message "drive.google.com refused to connect."

Tags: html, pdf, frontend, backend, google-docs

My test webpage got this line `<embed src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/17Z3Zvt63p3nI-C0BnOhPd75X5LSBi6dh/view?usp=sharing" width="840px" height="500px"/>` to display the PDF stored on the google drive. On visiting the webpage, I find the error "drive.google.com refused to connect." This file has been publicly shared and viewable if I just copy paste the link into the browser. Could you please help me rectify this?

On checking the console, I see this message "Refused to display 'https://drive.google.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'."

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>

/* Style the body */
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

/* Header/logo Title */
.header {
  padding: 80px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #1abc9c;
  color: white;
}

/* Increase the font size of the heading */
.header h1 {
  font-size: 40px;
}

/* Sticky navbar - toggles between relative and fixed, depending on the scroll position. It is positioned relative until a given offset position is met in the viewport - then it "sticks" in place (like position:fixed). The sticky value is not supported in IE or Edge 15 and earlier versions. However, for these versions the navbar will inherit default position */
.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  position: sticky;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  top: 0;
}

/* Style the navigation bar links */
.navbar a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}


/* Right-aligned link */
.navbar a.right {
  float: right;
}

/* Change color on hover */
.navbar a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

/* Active/current link */
.navbar a.active {
  background-color: #666;
  color: white;
}

/* Footer */
.footer {
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #ddd;
}

/* Responsive layout - when the screen is less than 700px wide, make the two columns stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */
@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .row {   
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}

/* Responsive layout - when the screen is less than 400px wide, make the navigation links stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */
@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  .navbar a {
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
.embed-pdf { 
  width: 840px;   
  height: 500px;   
  margin: auto; 
}

.pdfobject { border: 1px solid #666; }
</style>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="header">
  <h1>My Website</h1>
  <p>A <b>responsive</b> website created by me.</p>
</div>

<div class="navbar">
  <a href="#" class="active">Home</a>
  <a href="#">Link</a>
  <a href="#">Link</a>
  <a href="#" class="right">Link</a>
</div>

<div class="main">
    <h2>TITLE HEADING</h2>
    <p>Sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco.</p>
</div>

<div class="embed-pdf"> 
    <iframe src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/17Z3Zvt63p3nI-C0BnOhPd75X5LSBi6dh/preview" width="640" height="480" allow="autoplay"></iframe>
</div>

<div class="footer">
  <h2>Footer</h2>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i think u need to use iframe tag

Comment: Okay, will try and let you know

Comment: No, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Your source link is malformed.**

Whether you use  of  doesn't matter here because the tag doesn't know what to do with the source your providing.

To emded files from drive you have to specifically mention it by adding **"preview"** instead of **"view"** in the link.

Correct source link:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/17Z3Zvt63p3nI-C0BnOhPd75X5LSBi6dh/preview

This is the source you provided:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/17Z3Zvt63p3nI-C0BnOhPd75X5LSBi6dh/view?usp=sharing

**Note: You can also get the embed code by clicking the 3 dots on the top right of the screen and finding the "Embed item" option.**

[image]

[image]

ps: sorry i accessed your file

Comment: Nehan, thanks a lot for your solution. However, when I view the page in the mobile, I can only see the page number like 1/19 not the contents. I need the PDF to be visible on the mobiles too. Any advice?

Comment: I see that it is opening even on mobiles with Chrome. I just want it to be responsive. Could you please help me with it? I can share the HTML with you. This is a small test program(only HTML)

Comment: @PKTG remove the width and height attributes from the iframe. ie. the tag should be:

```<iframe src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/17Z3Zvt63p3nI-C0BnOhPd75X5LSBi6dh/preview" allow="autoplay"></iframe>```
Now you can declare widths and heights for the iframe on your stylesheet (css) so it stays responsive on all viewports.

Comment: Thank you, I just added the HTML to my post for you to add CSS to make it responsive across mobile device. Kindly add the CSS for me.

Comment: @PKTG https://pastebin.com/VEkpW2fs

Comment: Thanks a lot, man. It is made responsive now.

Comment: Nehan, could you please share your skype/email id?